# Where does the Windows command prompt "start" command look for programs?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

If you do something like `start firefox`, where does Windows look to figure out what `firefox` is?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#app_exe

Comment: Looks like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` was what I was missing. Thanks! If you want to post this as an answer I'll go and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It searches through the folders in the `PATH` environment variable (this is called the search path)

Comment: I was under the impression `PATH` was where Windows looked for programs in general. Like if I type `python` I can run Python because its path is in the `PATH` variable. But while I can use `start firefox` to run firefox, I can't run it with just `firefox`.